# Выделять ли запятыми слова "как никому" в составе сравнительного оборота?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

> Нам(,) как никому(,) повезло.

Нужны ли запятые?

Answer (score 2):

Нужны.

**[Вопрос № 204253](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83)**

> Помогите, пожалуйста! Нужны ли запяты е в этом случае: Тебе(?) как
>   никому другому(?) идут эти тона. Спасибо!

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Запятые нужны: *Тебе, как никому другому, идут эти тона*.

Специального правила на этот случай не нашла, но посмотрите (я выделю), как подобные ***нераспространённые*** обороты обособляются:

[**КАК НИГДЕ /…/ НИЧТО**,  *в составе сравнительного оборота*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_334)

Для начала - с конца:

> Обороты «как нигде», «как никто», «как никогда» и т. п., **тесно
>   связанные со сказуемым** и не имеющие при себе зависимых слов, не
>   обособляются.
>
> *Вильгельм ничего, кроме Дуни, не видел и не слышал. Она понимала его **как никто**.* Ю. Тынянов, Кюхля. *Он служил **как никогда**.* И. Бунин, Суходол. *Солнце пекло **как никогда**, но у пруда стояло
>   затишье.* Г. Белых, Л. Пантелеев, Республика ШКИД.

В Вашем примере нет этой тесной связи со сказуемым.

Далее (начало правила):

***Сравнительные обороты, начинающиеся словами «как нигде», «как никто», «как никогда» и т. д., обособляются.***

> *В Палестине, в Сирии, на берегу Средиземного моря совершенно особенно, **как нигде в мире**, гребут арабы.* Б. Пильняк, Повесть о
>   ключах и глине. *На партийном собрании, **как нигде**, коммунисты
>   познают многое, что в одиночку познать иногда не легко.* М. Бубеннов,
>   Белая береза. *Как я выжил, будем знать // Только мы с тобой, – //
>   Просто ты умела ждать, // **Как никто другой**.* К. Симонов, Жди меня.
>   *Контрразведчик должен знать, **как никто другой**, что верить в наше время нельзя никому – порой даже самому себе.* Ю. Семенов, Семнадцать
>   мгновений весны. *Он, **как никто**, знал, что не только история судит
>   побежденных.* В. Гроссман, Жизнь и судьба. *И город, // Артачась, //
>   Оголенный, // Без качеств, // И каменный, **как никогда**, // Стал
>   собой без стыда.* Б. Пастернак, Мужики и фабричные. *Я утром гуляла в
>   саду, в поле, была в лесу, мне казалось, что я одна во всем мире, и я
>   думала так хорошо, **как никогда в жизни**.* И. Бунин, Легкое дыхание.
>   *Всё было против людей Заозерья в то беспощадное утро: сушь и жара многих недель, состояние залежи и направление ветра, влажность воздуха
>   и низкий, **как никогда прежде**, уровень грунтовых вод.* Е. Парнов,
>   Третий глаз Шивы.

Answer (score 2):

**Нам, как никому, повезло.**  Но: Нам повезло **как никому.**

Обособление зависит от структуры предложения и позиции оборота.

**Пример без обособления:**

Антону повезло **как никому**. Он получил тяжелейшее ранение в голову, контузию, пролежал почти двенадцать часов на земле и… остался жив. [Дарья Донцова. (2003)]

**Правило:**

Из справочника В.М. Пахомов и др. "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" (2012). [http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?alpha=К](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?alpha=%D0%9A)

Возможны два варианта.

1) Обычно обороты такого вида обособляются: Он, **как никто**, знал, что не только история судит побежденных...

2) Обороты «как нигде», «как никто», «как никогда» и т. п., **тесно связанные со сказуемым и не имеющие при себе зависимых слов,** не обособляются. Вильгельм ничего, кроме Дуни, не видел и не слышал. Она понимала его **как никто**. Ю. Тынянов, Кюхля. Он служил как никогда. И. Бунин, Суходол.

О справочнике: http://gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_2726

Comment: У той же Донцовой: *А нам повезло, как никому, в доме есть свой полковник. [Дарья Донцова. Доллары царя Гороха (2004)]*. Ошибка?

Comment: Не ошибка.  Я уже отметила в свое ответе: "Обособление зависит от структуры предложения и позиции оборота". Другими словами, от разных факторов. Вы обратили внимание, что в одном случае это простое предложение, а в другом  сложное. В одном случае ударение удобно поставить только на обороте, обозначив тесную связь, а в другом можно сделать оборот попутным замечанием. Таким образом, правила дают возможность автору некоторую свободу, чтобы он мог выбрать оптимальное оформление своего текста.

Answer (score 2):

> Нам(,) как никому(,) повезло.
>
> Нужны ли запятые?

Думаю, автор, зная контекст и желая отразить на письме нужную интонацию, может выбрать любой из вариантов: и с запятыми, и без запятых.

При интонации, близкой к вводной, "как никому" стоит выделить запятыми. Логическое ударение в этом варианте будет на сказуемом:

— *Нам, как никому, **повезло**.*

При акцентировании слов "как никому" выделять запятыми их не нужно. К примеру, при таком контексте:

— *Нам сегодня повезло. Более того: нам **как никому** повезло!*